# Add data to database and retrieve dynamically in a textview

Tags: android, android-sqlite, textview

I am new to android development.

I want to add some data to database at the time of installation.

and in subsequent runs i want fetch the details from database and display that data in a clickable text view dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: show us what you have done.

Comment: Start by reading documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: @karakuri Thanks for link.i know how to insert into database. the thing is that i want it to be done only at the time of installation or at first launch.How can i do it? i have around 40 rows of data. Do i have to insert one by one or can i save that in a text or excel file and insert with loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can do these inserts in the onCreate of your SQLiteOpenHelper. That way if the user decides to clear your app data, the next time it creates a database, they will be inserted again.

```
public class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /* constructor and other stuff here */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQliteDatabase db) {
        db.execSql(...); // create table

        // do your inserts here
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. It's working fine now.  i have around 40 rows of data. Do i have to insert one by one or can i save that in a text or excel file and insert with loop?

Comment: That's really up to you whether you want to manage opening and reading a file while doing this process. It also may depend on your data. If you use the `db.insert(...)` method, then each row is inserted individually. You would have to use `db.execSql(...)` and write a raw sql insert statement to do it in one go. You could make the individual inserts faster by wrapping them all in a transaction: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()

Comment: Ok. Let me try that.   How can i retrieve the 40 rows from database and display that data in a clickable text view. i.e create 40 text views dynamically with data from database?

Comment: For that you will need to use a `ListView` and an adapter. When you query the database, you will get a `Cursor` with the results. You can then either use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` or create your own adapter implementation that is backed by a `Cursor`. I highly recommend watching The World of ListView for information on doing all of that: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=P9xgU4yZAYrw4gSCt4GYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=dhLVwts--wC_Br4j6GpmpQ